# AS3: Access button from class

Tags: actionscript-3, class, button

So im quite new to AS3 but have worked with AS2 a lot before.
I have created a button and placed it on my stage then inside my class i have added this:

```
    test.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonClicked);
    function buttonClicked(ev:MouseEvent):void
    {
        trace("Clicked");
    }
```

Now this does not work as it can't find the stage, the only way i can get this to work is if i put the listener on the same frame as the button & not in the class.

But there must be away around this.

Thank you.
Eli

**Update - adding Error messages**

If I keep the above code all in the external class these are the errors i get.

> Line 22   1120: Access of undefined property test. Line 22    1120: Access
>   of undefined property myButtonClick.

Comment: when you say class, do you mean document class?  You're using the Flash IDE presumably?   If you post your .fla it would be more helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.

I was being rava stupid as normal, forgot to put them inside the init :|

*For the people who might come across this problem.*
Working Code:

```
    public function Main()
    {
        // constructor code
        test.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, myButtonClick);

    }
        function myButtonClick(ev:MouseEvent):void
    {
        trace("button Clicked);
    }
```

Anyway thanks guys for the help sometimes its just the simplest answers are the correct ones.


Eli

Answer (score 1):

If you have created a document class with timeline then your "test" button must be in first frame. Because document class starts executing from first frame. You can access your button instance only when its available in stage.

Oh, I forgot to mention. You have to declare those instances as public variable in your document class.

```
public var test:SimpleButton;
```

Comment: it is on the first frame. read the above script to see the errors i get.

Answer (score 0):

Please go thru below and let me know which of the way you were having.

1) Are you having Document class?
There is a field **Class** in the Document Properties under the **Publish** tab of the flash IDE, if you are giving your class name in that field then it is called as **Document Class**

If you are having document class then you can create listener to your button even in the constructor button. Flash won't throw any errors like you got.

2) If you are instantiated your class in the first frame, it won't have the properties of **stage** till you add that to the stage using **addChild**. Also it won't have access to your button. And so it will throw the error, **The access of undefined property.**

Comment: If so, where you are trying to create listener to your button. Also please make sure if you are having more than one scene or frame, you have moved to that scene or frame before trying to access.

Comment: I only have 1 Frame & 1 Scene, I am trying to put the listener for my button inside my Document Class but i just get errors basically saying it can't be found. It does work if i put the listener on the 1st Frame keeping the function in the Document Class. But i want everything coding wise to be inside the Document Class.

Comment: I am not sure it is a typing error or not. But please check there is a string literal error in your function myButtonClick. You should close the string "button clicked" like this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you assigned the instance of the button on the stage the name "test"?  The error message you posted seems to say there is nothing with the name "test" to assign the event listener to.

To check, click on the button the stage and look at the 'Properties' tab:  will show in a text box near the top if it needs assigning.

Now the second error you posted means you're referring to something called "myButtonClick" without first declaring/initialising a variable/function with that name. You will either need to declare it or correct it if you meant to refer to something else.

Comment: Yes the button on stage does have the instance name of "test" & the myButtonClick is declared its right below.